# Wikipedia viewer linux online customizable

Tags: linux, wiki, wikimedia

I need a Wikipedia viewer that can fetch articles from Wikipedia and display them as styled by the user. That is, it should use a stylesheet (a settings window is also fine) to display the content in that style.

It would be appreciated if it has the ability to store the articles for offline reading.

The need of this has risen as the Wikipedia website looks old and I need a few offline articles, not the whole Wikipedia. I know these features exist in Wikipedia's mobile apps, but is there anything similar for Linux (elementary os)?

Comment: Would Android count as Linux for the purposes of this question, or will only elementary OS due?

Comment: @PyRulez No i have mentioned android just to compare the web version vs the app on android , i need the software on linux(elementary) only

Comment: What about using a user styleeshet (so you can use your favorite browser for displaying/saving the articles)?

Comment: Have you tried getting the articles in ZIM format and setting a custom style with Kiwix, the offline viewer for MediaWiki (and more)? http://www.kiwix.org/